# Splash screen while executing asynctask

Tags: android, splash-screen

I need to display a splash screen in my app but I don't know how to do it.
I have a Main Activity in where some images are downloaded from a server, by calling a function in another class, and I want the splash screen screen to be shown until the images are ready to be displayed.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
   //This is where the images are loaded
    new ClasePeticionRest.CogerObjetosAleatoriosInicio(this).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: 1. Display the splash image. 2. Run the AsyncTask. 3. On it's postExecute() make the images visible and the splash view gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a splash activity class and create asyncTask Class like below:

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

do your connections in `doInBackground` then in your `onPostExecute` write an intent to go to your Main Activity to display the Images:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

this will do the job for you